# Debugging when GitLab's CI complaining node can't be found

Tags: debugging, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm updating an existing project that uses a proprietary command line tool called `packs` to build a set of HTML and Javascript files. The project then uses Gitlab's CI to run the tool and deploy the resulting files to Gitlab Pages.

I've also updated the `packs` tool, and now the Gitlab CI is broken. Here's the relevant part of the CI log (with CI_DEBUG_TRACE set to true)

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.3.2
warning package.json: No license field
$ packs --build
/usr/bin/env: node
: No such file or directory
```

When I move back to an older version of `packs`, the CI part works. `packs` is installed with `npm`.

*Obviously* there's something wrong with the new version of `packs`, however, for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. When I run it locally it just works. I created a Docker image based on the same image as we use in CI (node:8) and it also works flawlessly.

I tried using `gitlab-runner` locally, it just wouldn't run properly (it couldn't mount a local drive, and the documentation is so poor they actually decided to drop support to the `exec` command).

I'm completely and utterly stuck, and how no idea how to proceed besides starting to delete random sections of packs until I find the problematic line.

Comment: The same happened with my sample GitHub project integrated with travis for a node package and one fine day, the build errored and when I cloned the repo locally, it worked alright! 
So, just to give you a tip, there is an EnvInject Plugin that "Injects environment variables at node (master/slave) startup" because I remember reading somewhere that there is a node command/switch to rollback if the current package version has any issue but can't recall what it was.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was CRLF line endings.

I'm using Windows most of the times, and although git converts line endings to LFs, npm does not. The first file - `index.ts` of the utility starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env node<CRLF>
```

tsc compiles to to Javascript, but its default behavior is to keep the line endings as is, so on Gitlab's CI docker container the CR was there, and the error was actually `/usr/bin/env node not found.

Telling tsc to generate LF line endings and making sure git doesn't convert them back to CRLFs on Windows solved the issue.

I still don't understand why I couldn't recreate this problem when trying a docker container based on the same image as Gitlab does.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13203